# jmeter -How to set max value in Aggregate report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a test plan for Rest API with one thread group with 2 samplers within.
While running load test for

- no of threads(users):80
- Ramp up period: 1

I get "Response code: 504 Response message: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT" in jmeter.

I observed that when Max value in Aggregate graph reaches 60000ms all response gets timed out.
What need to be done to prevent time out issue.
Load test works fine when I use 50 users or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting timeouts because at load of 80+ users, response time shoots up but your application or rest API's have less time out duration set. Because of heavy response times you are exceeding time out duration and getting those errors.

To resolve this issue simplest solution would be to increase time out values if possible.

Otherwise you need to improve response time of those Rest API's to a better value so that you won't get timeouts.
 
While doing this, monitor system utilization to be sure that changes are not hampering anywhere else.

From what you are saying it seems your application limit is ~60 users load with given configuration.

Answer (score 0):

please check you ELB settings , or application server settings(glassfish/apache) , ELB has by default 59 seconds of time out , after that ELB would time expire your request .

But you can see the response for those requests in the DB which might have taken longer time to respond